# Insertar varios arreglos con PHP MySql

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un programa con php pero esta es la primera vez que necesito ingresar varias arreglos en una tabla. 
Yo sé que en los input debo de colocar [] pero a la hora de hacer la consulta de insertar como debo hacer?
Lo que yo presento en el código solo me guarda el último valor sin los [], y en la consola pasa los valores que necesito, pero solo inserta el último valor.

Este es el código que tengo, no es muy complicado asi que agradeceria si me ayudan :)

```
  <form class="" action="asignar-fechas.php" method="post">
<?php foreach ($infoGrupo2 as $iGrupo2){
  if(($iGrupo2['fechaInicio']==$fechaA['numero_fecha'])){
      ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_grupo2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['id_grupo'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="modo2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['modo'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="fecha2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['fechaInicio'];?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="participante[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo['participante'];?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="jugador<?php echo $juga;?>[]" value="<?php echo $in2['id_users'];?>">
}?>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ASIGNAR FECHAS">
```

asignar-fechas.php

```
    $id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo2'];
  $modo = $_POST['modo2'];
  $fecha = $_POST['fecha2'];
  $participante = $_POST['participante'];
  $j1 = $_POST['jugador1'];
  $j2 = $_POST['jugador2'];
  $j3 = $_POST['jugador3'];
  $j4 = $_POST['jugador4'];

$insertarF = "INSERT INTO fechaxgrupo (grupo, fecha,estado) VALUES (:grupo, :fecha,0)";
    $insertF = $conn->prepare($insertarF);
    $insertF->bindParam(':grupo', $id_grupo);
    $insertF->bindParam(':fecha', $fechaa);
    $insertF->execute();
```

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta. Si es cuestión de insertar una fila por cada valor del arreglo entonces tienes que hacer las inserciones dentro de un bucle como bien te han dicho en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un foreach o consultarlo directamente accediendo con el indice

ejemplo:

```
foreach($_POST['jugador1'] as $item)
{
}
```

ó

```
$_POST['jugador1'][0]
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, perdón la ignorancia, pero donde debe implementarse el foreach? al realizarse cada consulta?